# Create a custom log file using a txt file in Batch

Tags: logging, for-loop, batch-file

I have a directory of files like such:

```
PDEN51505_1_1_N611729_15894285.XML
PDEN51505_1_2_N611729_15894286.XML
PDEN51505_2_1_N599021_15746279.XML
```

I need to create a custom log file for these files that will ultimately look like this:

```
462121  14105618    PD  EN  97240   1   97240               RF  PDEN51505_1_1_N611729_15894285  XML         C       N   N   0
462121  14105618    PD  EN  97240   1   97240               RF  PDEN51505_1_2_N611729_15894286  XML         C       N   N   0
462121  14105618    PD  EN  97240   1   97240               RF  PDEN51505_2_1_N599021_15746279  XML         C       N   N   0
```

Instead of me modifying the individual lines in the custom log file each time, I'm creating an automation process to build it for me. Here is what I have so far:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
MODE con: cols=125 lines=50
SET /P WHERE=Where are the XMLs located (full file path)? (default: %CD%)
IF "%WHERE%"=="" (
    SET WHERE=%CD%\
    ) ELSE (
        IF "!WHERE:~-1!"=="\" (
            SET WHERE=!WHERE!
        )   ELSE    (
            SET WHERE=!WHERE!\
        )
    )

:: TRAVERSE TO DIRECTORY THE USER JUST INPUT
CD %WHERE%

:: CREATES AN TEMP OUTPUT FILE OF THE DIRECTORY (MINUS EXTENTIONS)
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *.xml') DO ECHO %%~na>>output.txt

:: CLEARS OUT "PDEN" VARIABLES
FOR /f "delims==" %%i IN ('set PDEN 2^>nul') DO (SET %%i=)

:: CREATES A LISTING SEPERATED BY SPACES
FOR /f "tokens=*delims=_" %%a IN (output.txt) DO (
        SET PDEN=!PDEN! %%a
)

:: ATTEMPTS TO GENERATE A LOG FILE
FOR /f "tokens=*delims=" %%i IN ('set PDEN 2^>nul') DO (
            >%WHERE%PDEN_GEN_LOG.log ECHO 462121    14105618    PD  EN  97240   1   97240               RF  !PDEN!  XML         C       N   N   0
            ECHO [INFO] Generated PDEN_GEN_LOG.log
)

:: PROMPTS USER IF THEY WANT TO SEE THEIR CREATION
ECHO FINISHED
ECHO A new control file has been saved to %WHERE%
SET /P FILESURE=Would you like to view the LOG file you created?(Y/[N])?
IF /I "%FILESURE%" NEQ "Y" GOTO REMOVE
notepad.exe %WHERE%PDEN_GEN_LOG.log

:: REMOVES THE OUTPUT.TXT FILE
:REMOVE
RM %WHERE%output.txt
exit
```

It does everything right upto the point of creation. It's taking the list previously generated in output.txt and putting it on one line, so right now my log files are looking like this:

```
462121  14105618    PD  EN  97240   1   97240               RF   PDEN51505_1_1_N611729_15894285 PDEN51505_1_2_N611729_15894286 PDEN51505_2_1_N599021_15746279   XML         C       N   N   0
```

On top of that, each time I execute.bat the %PDEN% seems to grow in size. Do I need to flush that variable?

Help wanted!

Thanks y'all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion, try this:

```
@ECHO OFF & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
MODE con: cols=125 lines=50
set "where=%cd%"
SET /P "WHERE=Where are the XMLs located (full file path)? (default: %CD%) "
IF "%WHERE%"=="" SET "WHERE=%CD%\"
IF not "%WHERE:~-1%"=="\" SET "WHERE=%WHERE%\"

:: TRAVERSE TO DIRECTORY THE USER JUST INPUT
CD "%WHERE%"

:: delete Logfiles
DEL PDEN_GEN_LOG_*.log >nul 2>&1

:: CREATES A LISTING
set /a filecounter=0
FOR /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /on *.xml') DO (
set /a logcounter=!filecounter!/25+1
>>PDEN_GEN_LOG_!logcounter!.log ECHO 462121    14105618    PD  EN  97240   1   97240               RF  %%~na  XML         C       N   N   0
set /a filecounter+=1
)
ECHO [INFO] Generated PDEN_GEN_LOG_1.log to PDEN_GEN_LOG_%logcounter%.log

:: PROMPTS USER IF THEY WANT TO SEE THEIR CREATION(S)
ECHO FINISHED
ECHO New control file(s^) created in %WHERE%
SET /P "FILESURE=Would you like to view the LOG file(s^) you created?(Y/[N])? "
IF /I "%FILESURE%" NEQ "Y" exit
for /l %%i in (1,1,%logcounter%) do start "" "notepad.exe" PDEN_GEN_LOG_%%i.log
exit
```

This makes LOGs for every 25 files (the last log may contain less). You can change this number in this line: `set /a logcounter=!filecounter!/25+1`.

Comment: I had to make one modification where it says `)>PDEN_GEN_LOG.log` I had to change it to `)>>PDEN_GEN_LOG.log`. It was only capturing the last one in the directory.

Comment: Finally, is there a way to add in that when it gets to the 25th file in the directory create another `PDEN_GEN_LOG` file counting up in sequence? ie: `PDEN_GEN_LOG_1.log`, `PDEN_GEN_LOG_2.log`, etc...

There will be times where there is a massive amount of files in the directory and I don't want it all jammed up in one log file.

Help much appreciated

Comment: I can add a counter to create one log for each xml. Or what do you mean?

Comment: If the directory contains 100 XMLs I need it to create 4 log files each containing 25 entries.

Comment: OK, it needs some addinional code. I can do this later, now on the Android tablet ...

Comment: You're the man. Very helpful! Take your time, I'm heading off to bed myself.